# Uniqueness of constructed solutions to the Helmholtz equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, wave-equation

My question is regarding the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with real wavenumber $k$ and outgoing radiation condition

\begin{equation}
\Delta u + k^2 u = - f \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{r\to \infty} r(\partial_r - ik)u = 0 \quad \text{on } S^2.   
\end{equation}
It is well known that for, say, $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ there is a unique solution $u \in H^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and that the solution is given by a convolution with the fundamental solution, i.e.,

$$ u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{ik|x-y|}}{4\pi |x-y|} f(y) dy. $$

My confusion stems from the following considerations (which again stem from trying to manufacture a solution for testing the convergence of a numerical method):

For a ball $B_r$ centered at $0$ and radius $r$, take $v \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and assume $v$ is real valued and such that $\text{supp}(v) \subset B_{r}$. Then set   $\tilde{f} = - (\Delta  + k^2 )v$.

By construction, $v$ satisfies the Helmholtz equation with right-hand side $-\tilde{f}$, and $v = 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus B_r$, and so it satisfies the radiation condition. Therefore, it should be the unique, real-valued solution to the problem.

However, if we write

\begin{align}
V(x) &= v_1(x) + iv_2(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{e^{ik|x-y|}}{4\pi |x-y|} \tilde{f}(y) dy\\
 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\cos(k|x-y|)}{4\pi |x-y|} \tilde{f}(y) dy + i\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\sin(k|x-y|)}{4\pi |x-y|} \tilde{f}(y)dy,
\end{align}

there is no reason for the imaginary part $v_2(x)$ to vanish everywhere.

But we should have
$$(\Delta + k^2)V = (\Delta + k^2)v_1 + (\Delta + k^2)iv_2 = -\tilde{f}$$
and as $\tilde{f}$ is real-valued, we must have $(\Delta + k^2)v_2 = 0$, and by uniqueness $v_2 = 0$.

My question is therefore what to make of the imaginary part $v_2$ of the solution $V$ given by the convolution with the fundamental solution? And is there something wrong with my initial constructed solution $v$ that disqualifies it from being a solution to the Helmholtz equation with Sommerfeld radiation condition?

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old Sherlock Holmes adage

> When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

applies here. Since nothing else you did was wrong, it must be your idea that

> there is no reason for the imaginary part $v_2$ to vanish everywhere

that is faulty. So let me give you the reason.

First consider the function $\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Note that the sinc function is real analytic and even, so $\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now you can compute, in polar coordinates for convenience,
$$ \Delta \frac{\sin(kr)}{r} = \frac{1}{r} \partial^2_{rr} \sin(kr) = - k^2\frac{\sin(kr)}{r} $$
which shows the **key fact** that

$$(\Delta + k^2) \frac{\sin(kr)}{r} = 0.$$

Given any function $w$, smooth with compact support, you can integrate by parts

$$ \int \frac{\sin(k|x|)}{|x|} (\Delta + k^2) w(x) ~dx = \int w(x) (\Delta + k^2) \frac{\sin(k|x|)}{|x|} ~dx = 0. $$

Now for any given $y\in \mathbb{R}^3$, set $w(x) = -v(y-x)$ for the $v$ in your question, and you check therefore the imaginary part of $v_{2}(y) = 0$.

---

Note, however, the final integration by parts may fail to be valid when $w$ is not decaying sufficiently fast. Taking care of this "boundary condition at infinity" is why you impose the radiation condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great answer!